# How to call kernel code in libc ? (windows or linux)

Tags: glibc, libc, masm32

I mean, how the kernel expose its function to user land application.

Comment: The kernel of which operating system ?

Comment: @Paul if all is in the some way, then anyone.

Comment: you're going to have to be a little more specific - as it stands the question is just way too vague and will probably be closed unless you add more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel functions are called using syscalls, which usually take form of filling some registers (type of syscall, parameters, ...) and doing a software interrupt (int 0x80) or sysenter instruction (if your architecture supports it).

If you're doing this on Linux, you might want to see some Linux syscall documentation, like one here: http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html

There surely exists some similar documentation for other kernels (windows').

Comment: Basically, yes. This article shows a bit about windows http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-syscall-shellcode

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about Linux, you put your arguments in registers and call interrupt 0x80.  The name for this is "system call"
See these links:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-system-calls/
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4048

Windows is probably similar, this looks like a good article:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/devicedriverdevelopment/article.php/c8035

etc... google